# DataSet call insert, update and delete stored procedures

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, strongly-typed-dataset

Through designer I have created a typed data set and included stored procedures for insert / update / delete. The problem is now, how to call those stored procedures? How to actually change data in database this way? And how to receive answer from db (number of rows changed)?

[image]

Comment: You need to create an instance of the table adapter, then use the Fill or GetData methods of the ta to return data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that far easiest way is through designer - create table adapter and simply set it to call stored procedure. No extra typing needed, arguments are also added to procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

try this for get data from database. 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("dstblName");
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
    {
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("spselect", conn);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", parameter1value);
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
            da.Fill(ds);
     }

Similarly you need to call "spdelte" etc.

Comment: That's what I am doing already and I am asking myself if there is a better way to do it. With lots of arguments - lots of typing, each and every time, for every stored procedure particulary in database.